# How to manage multiple sessions in AWS Lex using a single Lamba instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

How to manage multiple sessions in AWS Lex using AWS Lambda, as in the approach I have done I store the event['userId'] and compare it, but the problem is when another user(B) tries to chat with the bot at the same time or after user(A), the event['userId'] changes as user(B) has most recently invoked the lambda function, changing the event['userId']. Even if user(A) tries to chat again there is no response from AWS Lambda as the event['userId'] changed. Any way to fix this?

Thanks in advance

[I'm trying to compare the userId but User(A) event['userId'] is lost track of, and the latest/last event['userId'] is only available (worklist is a list of user objects.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suONS.png)

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve by managing and storing state within the Lambda function?

Lex can handle multiple sessions by itself. Lambdas are intended to be stateless so trying to preserve state within the Lambda function based on the last invocation is counter to this principle.

You can, of course, introduce state in your Lambda function by storing state information in something like S3 and DynamoDB.

I assume your Lambda function is getting called from another application and that application is passing in some information like a user id and user input as parameters. You can use that information - specifically the user id - to retrieve the necessary state from DynamoDB, invoke Lex, and then gather and store the updated state in DynamoDB.

This way, your application remains stateless while still having the ability to use the correct user state when interacting with Lex.